# Find a, b, c and d of a function $f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + 1$, given values f(1), f(2), f(3), ...

Tags: functions, interpolation

I have a (very-likely) 4-grade function, and I know all the values, but I am having problems to find the formula of the function itself.

The number without the `x` is a one for sure.

The functions points are:

```
(0  |    1)
(1  |    9)
(2  |   41)
(3  |  129)
(4  |  321)
(5  |  681)
(6  | 1289)
```

I have been calculated with the following starting-grid:

$$
\begin{cases}
   a + b + c + d + 1 = 9\\
   16a + 8b + 4c + 2d + 1 = 41\\
   81a + 27b + 9c + 3d + 1 = 129\\
   256a + 64b + 16c + 4d + 1 = 321\\
\end{cases}
$$

I came to a = $2\over3$, b = $4\over3$, c = $16\over3$, d = $2\over3$, yet it's [another](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282n%5E4%20%2B%204n%5E3%20%2B%2016n%5E2%20%2B%202n%20%2B%203%29%2F3) function.

I have over 2 pages of calculations and handwriting only I can read, so my question is: Can I calculate it much faster/ simpler/ cleaner? - Checking through every addition to find one mistake just seems lame.

Is there an online (free) calculator for stuff like these?

PS. Be nice to add the tag `find-formula` :)

Comment: Note that you have $7$ points, so by substitution $7$ equations, but only $4$ unknowns. It is possible that there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: As for finding a polynomial passing through given points, you can have a look at Lagrange polynomial (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: @PeterForeman, I've added one more point (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C+9%7D%2C%7B2%2C+41%7D%2C%7B3%2C+129%7D%2C%7B4%2C+321%7D%2C%7B5%2C+681%7D%2C%7B6%2C+1683%7D%2C+%7B7%2C+3653%7D%7D) and it even seems to "be" a function of 15th or more degree - I am very sure that can't be the case.

Comment: But there's a mistake I have accidentally made - for x = 6 it's meant to be 1289. This one is a 4th-grade function. I am very sorry for the confusion: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C+9%7D%2C%7B2%2C+41%7D%2C%7B3%2C+129%7D%2C%7B4%2C+321%7D%2C%7B5%2C+681%7D%2C%7B6%2C+1289%7D%7D

Comment: @PeterForeman yes, one of the points I have included was sadly a mistyped. (I was in another row/column probably)

Comment: @AnatolyWein Wolfram should give you the polynomial of minimal degree. Is this the answer you required?

Comment: Are you familiar with machine learning (specifically curve fitting)? And why are you trying to use polynomial in the first place at all?

Comment: @PeterForeman yes, that's a answer I appreciate.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald, I am starting with neuronal networks, so I can't say that I am familiar with machine learning.

Comment: +1. It's a great question, and stimulated good answers. Also I noticed you followed my Materials Modeling Stack Exchange proposal. We are now in the commitment stage and it would be very very helpful if you could click commit! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MGFkOGRlMTg1ODg2NTUxZDQ1MDVjZmQyOTg1ZDcxODQzMjc0OGIyMjBhZDM4ZDQ5MzM0MWE1YzZhNDBjMzhlYfHJBfp5EvPDPybryqjeDgXYucHU-wUv4jp4j6imjIfF0 Only 2.7% of the people fulfill commitment on new proposals so it doesn't matter if you can't participate much, but it would be very very helpful if you can commit.

Answer (score 1):

In the comment section of the answer I found the `interpolating polynomial {{0,1},{1, 9},{2, 41},{3, 129},{4, 321},{5, 681},{6, 1289}}` method for wolfram alpha. The solution is

$$2 x^4 + 4 x^3 + 10 x^2 + 8 x + 3 \over 3$$

so a, b, c and d are equivalently $2\over3$, $4\over3$, $10\over3$, $8\over3$

Answer (score 1):

Given $7$ distinct data points , we can use [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) in the [Lagrange  from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) such that:

$\color{red}{\left(0,1\right)},\color{green}{\left(1,9\right)},\color{pink}{\left(2,41\right)},\color{blue}{\left(3,129\right)},\left(4,321\right),\color{olive}{\left(5,681\right)},\color{orange}{\left(6,1289\right)}$

$$\sum_{j=0}^{6}y_{j}l_{j}\left(x\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{6}y_{j}\prod_{0\le m\le6}^{ }\frac{x-x_{m}}{x_{i}-x_{m}}$$$$=\frac{x-1}{0-1}\frac{x-2}{0-2}\frac{x-3}{0-3}\frac{x-4}{0-4}\frac{x-5}{0-5}\frac{x-6}{0-6}\color{red}{\cdot1}+$$$$\frac{x-0}{1-0}\frac{x-2}{1-2}\frac{x-3}{1-3}\frac{x-4}{1-4}\frac{x-5}{1-5}\frac{x-6}{1-6}\color{green}{\cdot9}+$$$$\frac{x-0}{2-0}\frac{x-1}{2-1}\frac{x-3}{2-3}\frac{x-4}{2-4}\frac{x-5}{2-5}\frac{x-6}{2-6}\color{pink}{\cdot41}+$$$$\frac{x-0}{3-0}\frac{x-1}{3-1}\frac{x-2}{3-2}\frac{x-4}{3-4}\frac{x-5}{3-5}\frac{x-6}{3-6}\color{blue}{\cdot129}+$$$$\frac{x-0}{4-0}\frac{x-1}{4-1}\frac{x-2}{4-2}\frac{x-3}{4-3}\frac{x-5}{4-5}\frac{x-6}{4-6}\cdot321+$$$$\frac{x-0}{5-0}\frac{x-1}{5-1}\frac{x-2}{5-2}\frac{x-3}{5-3}\frac{x-4}{5-4}\frac{x-6}{5-6}\color{olive}{\cdot681}+$$$$\frac{x-0}{6-0}\frac{x-1}{6-1}\frac{x-2}{6-2}\frac{x-3}{6-3}\frac{x-4}{6-4}\frac{x-5}{6-5}\color{orange}{\cdot1289}$$

Another way would be using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).